# Proper notation for distinct sets

Tags: notation, elementary-set-theory

Consider I have two sets that neither one is a subset of the other (for example, the set of prime numbers and the set of odd integers). Is there a specific notation that combines the meanings of both ⊄ and ⊅ ?

Also, is there a notation to mean that two sets are completely distinct and share no elements in common (for example, the sets of odd and even integers)?

≠ seems very inappropriate, and I'd like to avoid it.

**Context:** My area is actually Computer Science. I'm using this refine my vocabulary in order to teach my students about [subnetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) (which is basically about sets and subsets of IP addresses), and to write some exercises for them. I'll probably use the words *incomparable* and *disjoint* as suggested.

Comment: This can be expressed as $(A \subset B) \downarrow (B \subset A)$, where $\downarrow$ is [nor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no special symbol to denote the situation in which neither set is contained in the other. There *is* a special word, though: we say the two sets are **incomparable.**

There is also no special symbol to denote the fact that two sets are disjoint; we simply write $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\rm\:P\: $ be a poset = [partially-ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), i.e. a set equipped wth a relation $\rm\le$ that is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. Then one says that $\rm\: x\: $ and $\rm\: y\: $ are *comparable*$\ $ if $\rm\ x \le y\ $ or $\rm\ y \le x\:;\: $ otherwise they are *incomparable*, sometimes written $\rm\ x||y\:.\:$ A *chain*$\ $ of  $\rm\: P\:$ is a subset in which every two elements are comparable, and dually, an *antichain*$\ $ is a subset in which every two elements are incomparable.

Comment: (@Juliano: any collection of sets is a poset under the subset relation, which is why this terminology is applicable.)

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, perhaps an interesting historical curiousity. [George Mackey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Mackey) (my professor years ago) hoped to popularize this symbol as a binary relation for disjoint sets:

[image]

I think he meant it as a lower case "d" drawn symmetrically.

The screen shot suggests that $\TeX$ doesn't know it.

**Edit:** This question on $\TeX$  stackexchange provides an update: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554944/looking-for-a-disjoint-symbol

Answer (score 0):

If subsets $A,B$ are distinct elements of a partition of $U$, then $A \not\sim B$ or $A \not\equiv B$ are perfectly conventional for denoting disjointness as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). (You can make a convenience partition - if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ - as $U = \{A,B, (A \cup B)^c \}$). Similarly, taking any $a \in A, b \in B$ you can write $[a] \not\sim [b]$.